# How can I evaluate $\int \frac{5x^3+2}{x^3-5x^2+4x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I calculate the following:
$$\int \frac{5x^3+2}{x^3-5x^2+4x}dx$$ 
I think long division might help me, but I can't understand how to do it here, nor if it will help.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, **[polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)** will help you, after which you'll need to use **[partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)**, noting that $$x^3-5x^2+4x = x(x^2 - 5x + 4) = x(x-1)(x - 4)$$

For further assistance with polynomial long division, visit ***[Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/DividingPolynomials.aspx)***

Comment: The problem is I can't understand how to divide$ 5x^3+2$  by $x^3-5x^2+4x $ . I get $5$ + a remainder ? 
I am a little bit confused. Thanks !

Comment: Read through the linked entry at Wikipedia. Yes, you'll get $5$ and a remainder.

Comment: Got it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need polynomial division and partial fraction decomposition. Note that the denominator can easily be factored. Since the denominator splits in linear factors,
you will get a sum of logarithms of linear functions.